# Converting java.util.function.Function to kotlin

Tags: kotlin

The java code :

```
public class Neuron implements Comparable<Neuron>, Serializable {

public interface Activation extends Function<Float, Float>, Serializable {
    Activation SIGMOID = z -> 1 / (1 + (float) Math.exp(-z));
    Activation LINEAR = z -> z;
    Activation TANH = x -> (float) Math.tanh(x);
}
...
```

somehow, i managed to translate it to this kotlin code (with the help of various answer i found on stackoverflow) :

```
class Neuron(
val id: Int,
val inputs: Array<Neuron?>,
val weights: FloatArray,
var type: Type?,
private var activation: (Float) -> Float,
val label: String?
) : Comparable<Neuron>, Serializable {

interface Activation : Function<Float?, Float?>, Serializable {
    companion object {
        val SIGMOID = fun(z: Float): Float { return 1 / (1 + exp(-z)) }
        val LINEAR = fun(z: Float): Float { return z }
        val TANH = fun(x: Float): Float  { return tanh(x) }
    }
}
```

I'm probably doing it wrong and i still have some error when i try to use it.
The very good news is that, while my code is still a mix of java and kotlin, this code is only called by kotlin code. So there could be a way to solve it all in a proper way.

I fixed a lot of stuff here and there to fix argument type in various method/function but i'm stuck with this one :

```
fun tick() {
    nextState = 0.0f
    for (i in inputs.indices) nextState += inputs[i]!!.state * weights[i]
    nextState = activation!!.apply(nextState)!!
}
```

the errors, on the same line :

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is (Float) -> Float but Float? was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is Float but TypeVariable(T).() -> Unit was expected
```

The first error is probably related to the type of "nextState" (which is indeed a Float), but apply is supposed to return a Float so i assume that solving the 2nd error will fix the 1st one. I don't understand the 2nd error.

Considering that SIGMOID, LINEAR, TANH, are (as far as i know) only called from Kotlin code, is there a way to fix it all in a graceful way ?

A temporary fix i just found :

```
nextState = activation.invoke(nextState)
```

is this the proper way to solve it all ? is there perhaps a nicer solution without interface and companion ? should i leave it as is and call it a day ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question since the full, clean, solution is a mixture of multiple answers and comments.

---

I replaced `nextState = activation!!.apply(nextState)!!`

with `nextState = activation(nextState)`

using `nextState = activation.invoke(nextState)` also worked but wasn't necessary.

---

I replaced

```
interface Activation : Function<Float?, Float?>, Serializable {
    companion object {
        val SIGMOID = fun(z: Float): Float { return 1 / (1 + exp(-z)) }
        val LINEAR = fun(z: Float): Float { return z }
        val TANH = fun(x: Float): Float  { return tanh(x) }
    }
}
```

with

```
interface Activation : (Float) -> Float, Serializable {
    companion object {
        val SIGMOID: (Float) -> (Float) = { 1 / (1 + exp(-it)) }
        val LINEAR : (Float) -> (Float) = { it }
        val TANH   : (Float) -> (Float) = { tanh(it) }
    } 
}
```

And got rid of the java import.

---

Then i realized that i didn't need this interface since it was only called from Kotlin code.

I changed all reference to the `Activation` type to `(Float) -> Float` and removed the interface. I already had a companion object declared in this class so i moved it all in this companion object.

```
companion object {
    private const val serialVersionUID = 1L  // this one was already there
    val SIGMOID: (Float) -> (Float) = { 1 / (1 + exp(-it)) }
    val LINEAR : (Float) -> (Float) = { it }
    val TANH   : (Float) -> (Float) = { tanh(it) }
}
```

I changed all my reference to theses function from `Neuron.Activation.LINEAR` to `Neuron.LINEAR`

eg :

```
var defaultActivation = Neuron.Activation.LINEAR // with interface
var defaultActivation = Neuron.LINEAR // without interface
```

---

Thank you everyone. I hope this will help, it seems to be a common problem because intellij failed to convert automatically this kind code from java to kotlin using the builtin functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop this *Activation* interface in Kotlin because you never use it.

Instead you said in code you want your ***var activation*** to be of type *(Float) -> Float*. So you can do it like this

```
val SIGMOID: (Float) -> (Float) = { 1 / (1 + exp(-it)) }
...
```

Oh, and then you can use *activation(...)* syntax.

Comment: thiank you, i like this syntax. if i remove the interface, how do i make a reference to it ? exemple of existing code : var defaultActivation = Neuron.Activation.LINEAR

Comment: @ker2x if it's located inside companion of *Neuron*, then just Neuron.LINEAR. If you're referring to it inside Neuron itself, then just LINEAR

Comment: i get some error about conflicting declaration if i keep the companion object and just remove the interface. i don't really understand what's happening. i'll leave it as is for now. finish my conversion to full kotlin (i still have a lot of java code here and there) and the proceed to cleanup and make it proper kotlin code instead of semi-automated conversion from java. thank you for your help.

Comment: @ker2x If you remove *Activation.* from every reference then it should work without interface just fine

Comment: i found the problem. there was a 1 line companion object already declared (at the very bottom) in this class. Hence the conflicting declaration error. i moved the 3 lines inside the already declared companion object and that solved the error. I also removed the reference to Activation as well, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in android studio then a good way is to just copy the java code into a Kotlin file. You will be prompted to turn the code into kotlin. This worked for me when I had to copy code from online. I hope this works for you.

Comment: i'm in intellij idea. i am indeed using this conversion feature, but the conversion failed for this part and generated erroneous code.

Comment: Maybe you can try with one of the online editors?

Answer (score 0):

Probably change to

```
interface Activation : (Float?) -> Float?, Serializable {
  
}
```

Then the instances

```
 companion object {
        val SIGMOID = (Float) -> Float = { return 1 / (1 + exp(-z)) }
        val LINEAR = (Float) -> Float =  { return z }
        val TANH = (Float) -> Float =   { return tanh(x) }
    }
```

and usage to

```
activation(nextState)
```

which is equvalent to `.invoke(nextState)`

Comment: thank you, now i don't have to import java.util.function.Function anymore. calling activation directly also worked.  about the function itself, is there a difference with the conversion i provided or is it purely syntaxic sugar ? i find my val = fun easier to understand (probably because of my C/C++ background, this function pointer-ish style look more intuitive to me (i can't believe i'm writting this))

Comment: The problem with _both_ of these versions is that they produce function objects, not instances of the `Activation` interface.  (Note also that you probably shouldn't have `return`.)